# Get Data from 2 Json link in jquery

Tags: php, jquery, apache

code look like this

```
<script type = "text/javascript" language = "javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    function updateDiv(){
        $('#sp').html('');
        $.getJSON('info.php?hash=<?php echo $torrent_hash; ?>', function(data) {
        })
        .done(function( data ) {
            $.each(data, function( i, item ) {
                console.log(item.size);
                $('#sp').append(item.size).append('<br />');
            });
        });
    }
    updateDiv();
    setInterval(updateDiv, 10000);
});
</script>
```

where `$.getJson` get data from different json like which is create by `$torrent_hash`

and its look like for first hash value
http://localhost/final/info.php?hash=8195e4f6619ce780925d9952b358744dd81f1299

```
{
    "info":{
        "name":"War.on.Everyone.2016.HDRip.XViD-ETRG",
        "progress":0.02,
        "size":"706.72 MiB",
        "hash":"8195e4f6619ce780925d9952b358744dd81f1299",
        "peer":0,
        "speed":"0 Byte",
        "path":"C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\final\\download\/8195e4f6619ce780925d9952b358744dd81f1299"
    }
}
```

And Second Hash Value looks like
http://localhost/final/info.php?hash=5a1a5f86d71f46b53a2c4719f671555a0b33940e

```
{
    "info":{
        "name":"BOLLYGRAM 6th EDITION (UNPLUGGED) - (2016) DJ RINK (Remix)",
        "progress":0,
        "size":"64.59 MiB",
        "hash":"5a1a5f86d71f46b53a2c4719f671555a0b33940e",
        "peer":0,
        "speed":"0 Byte",
        "path":"C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\final\\download\/5a1a5f86d71f46b53a2c4719f671555a0b33940e"
    }
}
```

At console its fatch Both Data at a same time like this

```
706.72 MiB  sp.php:188 
64.59 MiB   sp.php:188 
64.59 MiB   sp.php:142 
706.72 MiB
```

> Here is my question when store this data to html `<p>` tag it only shows last data 64MiB instead of both data

I use `$('#sp').html(item.size);` to store data

> My Current Output like

```
War.on.Everyone.2016.HDRip.XViD-ETRG
size= 760Mib 63Mib
-------------------------------------
BOLLYGRAM 6th EDITION (UNPLUGGED) 
size = "Nothing Appear Here"
```

> I need Output Like this with one html `<p>` tage its possible to do this ?

```
War.on.Everyone.2016.HDRip.XViD-ETRG
size= 760Mib  
---------------------------------------------
BOLLYGRAM 6th EDITION (UNPLUGGED) 
size = 63Mib
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the line:

```
$('#sp').html(item.size);
```

You're replacing the HTML content not appending to it. Instead try this:

```
$('#sp').append(item.size);
```

If you want it cleared before the loop runs again add this before $.getJson:

```
$('#sp').html('');
```

Comment: And There Any Way to use this  $('#sp').append(item.size);  with Php While Condition Because its show  Both Size At  first Hash "name":"War.on.Everyone.2016.HDRip.XViD-ETRG",  I Mean The Output is Looks like War.on.Everyone.2016.HDRip.XViD-ETRG
size=
706.72 MiB
64.59 MiB



BOLLYGRAM 6th EDITION (UNPLUGGED) - (2016) DJ RINK (Remix) Full Album Mp3 320Kbps Groo
size=

Comment: If you want additional HTML, just chain more HTML: $('#sp').append(item.size).append('<br>'); or $('#sp').append(item.size + '<br>');

Comment: i use this both method but output look like this https://s27.postimg.org/u92yn4srn/download.png

Comment: @Amitya - This answer does answer your question and should be the accepted answer. I also think you should read up on some basic HTML, Javascript and Jquery.

Comment: @Amitya you might be outputting additional content elsewhere. You might try item.info.size instead of item.size, but I don't think that's the issue. I'm happy to help, but you shouldn't add new questions into the comments after your initial question is answered. Your first question is solved, happy to help on a separate question.